# Data length in PCM Wave file using MemoryStream with WaveFileWriter

Tags: naudio, pcm

**Scenario:**

I am using NAudio 1.5 and I am trying to record a Sinus wave from an IWaveProvider in format PCM, 8bit, 22050hz like this:

```
Private Sub record(ByVal waveForm As String, _
                   ByVal duration As Integer, _
                   ByVal frequency As Integer, _
                   ByVal amplitude As Integer, _
                   ByVal sampleRate As Integer)
    Dim wave As IWaveProvider = _
          Audio.SoundModulWaveFormProviderFactory.createWaveForm(waveForm, _
                frequency, amplitude, sampleRate)
    Dim memStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    Dim writer As New WaveFileWriter(memStream, wave.WaveFormat)
    Dim numberOfBytes As Integer = writer.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond
    Dim buffer(numberOfBytes) As Byte
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    For i = 1 To duration
        count = wave.Read(buffer, 0, numberOfBytes)
        writer.Write(buffer, 0, count)
    Next
    writer.Flush()
    Try
        Me.audioStream = New MemoryStream()
        memStream.WriteTo(Me.audioStream)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
    writer.Close()
    recorded = True
End Sub
```

The memory stream is then handed over to a function that is parsing the whole wave file and includes it into a list of sounds.

**Issue**

The above mentioned function expects the lenght of the wave data to be from byte-position 42 to 45. Unfortunately it seems that this is always 0. Thus I dont get any length back.

**Question:**

How can I make sure that the WaveFileWriter is writing this information into the MemoryStream? Or does it only do that upon writing to a file?

Maybe there is a different way of reaching the same goal?

**Update:**

WaveFileWriter does include the wave data lenght when writing to a file directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the length is only set by the WaveFileWriter when you call Close. So move writer.Close up before your Try block. Also, NAudio has a helper class called IgnoreDisposeStream, which you can use to prevent your MemoryStream from getting disposed before you want it to.

```
Dim writer As New WaveFileWriter(new IgnoreDisposeStream(memStream) ...

...
writer.Close()
Try
    Me.audioStream = New MemoryStream()
    memStream.WriteTo(Me.audioStream)
Catch ex As Exception
    Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try

recorded = True
```